# Python - Pandas - Edit duplicate items keeping last

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say my df is:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd'], 
'col2':[10,20, 30, 10, 20, 10, 10, 20, 30]})
```

How can I make all numbers zero keeping the last one only? In this case the result should be:

```
col1  col2
a     0
a     0
a     30
b     0
b     20
c     10
d     0
d     0
d     30
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use `loc` and [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with the argument `keep='last'`:

```
df.loc[df.duplicated(subset='col1',keep='last'), 'col2'] = 0

>>> df
  col1  col2
0    a     0
1    a     0
2    a    30
3    b     0
4    b    20
5    c    10
6    d     0
7    d     0
8    d    30
```